# Can't update datagridview and form elements in C#

Tags: c#

In C# using Visual Studio Express 2013, I am trying to update a datagridview from an event handler for a  button click. The button is a submit button that updates an Sqlite database and then updates the datagridview to reflect the change. The problem is that after I update the Sqlite database (which is updating successfully) the datagridview doesn't update from the event handler (This is set in the getLoggedData(employeeNumber, false) reference). (I also tried updating a text box, which didn't update). After the datagridview is supposed to update, I added a thread.sleep, so the user can see the changes that were made before the datagridview resets (getLoggedData() on the last line of the button click resets the datagridview).

The getLoggedData(employeeNumber, false) method just gets the sqlite database as a datatable and sets it as the datasource to dgvLogged. The check column and addRow shouldn't be related to the problem.

As a side note, I have already tried using a Binding Source to no avail.

```
// This is when the button submit is clicked
private void btnConfirmEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modifyEmployeeJobs();

        getLoggedData(employeeNumber, false);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        getLoggedData();
    }

public void getLoggedData(string empID, bool addRow)
    {
        dgvColumnNumberAdder = 1; // Adds a 1 to the index if the checkboxes are present in the datagridview
        MySql sql = new MySql();
        try
        {
            dgvLogged.Columns.Clear();

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkColumn.Name = "Check";
            checkColumn.HeaderText = "";
            checkColumn.Width = 50;
            checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
            checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
            checkColumn.MinimumWidth = 30;
            dgvLogged.Columns.Add(checkColumn);

            DataTable dt = sql.getLoggedData(empID);

            if (addRow)
            {
                // Add row to datatable for job information that was just received
                DataRow row;
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row["EmpID"] = employeeNumber;
                row["Job"] = jobNumber;
                row["WorkCode"] = workCode;
                row["JobState"] = "Pending";

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }                

            dgvLogged.DataSource = dt;
            dgvLogged.Columns[jobTrackingColumnNumbers["ID"] + dgvColumnNumberAdder].Visible = false;
            setCheckStates();
            dgvLogged.Visible = true;
            txtInstructions.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not want to do the thread sleep in a UI- if you want the user to be able to navigate for 2 seconds (which isn't a lot of time) kick off a timer that will do the same logic, and on elapsed do what you were going to do. Sleeping within that button call will lock the UI. Your last call for getLoggedData() calls a method with no arguments- where is that method?

Comment: Adding the timer instead of the thread sleep worked beautifully. Why would holding the UI for 2 secs stop the datagridview from updating if I tell the datagridview to update before I give the thread.sleep() command?

Comment: Because the UI thread is still running, and you sleep it, so you are waiting on that sleep to finish (on that thread) before moving to the next step which is to rebind the data. I cannot think of any reason to sleep on a UI thread, the UI is for display only, so you want to trigger updates to it by events and invokes. Remember that a form is a multithreaded environment even if you are not managing those threads.

Comment: I combined my responses into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are doing a `Thread.Sleep()` on your UI button event- this locks the thread that button event happens on until that sleep is complete.

You do not want to do the thread sleep in a UI. If you want the user to be able to navigate for 2 seconds you can kick off a `System.Timer` that, on elapsed finishes the rest of the logic you wanted to do. Sleeping within that button call will lock the UI because the UI thread is still running, and you sleep it, so you are waiting on that sleep to finish (on that thread) before moving to the next step which is to rebind the data.

I cannot think of any reason to sleep on a UI thread, the UI is for display only, so you want to trigger updates to it by events and invokes. Remember that a form is a multithreaded environment even if you are not managing those threads.

Comment: Are you saying the datagridview update happens on a thread outside the UI thread and the UI thread doesn't finish executing until the click event routine is complete? I guess I still don't understand, you say the data rebinding happens after the thread.sleep(), but in my code the datasource is updated first and then the thread.sleep() happens.

Comment: From my other comment though, you don't have the method `getLoggedData()` shown- My guess is that is a valid method, and does the update you want (and is then seen after the sleep happens). As for thread management for UI objects, that I do not know- I just know that they are on different threads and you should invoke them. I try not to mess with things that are auto generated by Visual Studio (aside from the designer section).